# In a String, how can I separate & store the characters and integers?

Tags: java, string, char, int, type-conversion

My task is to create a Bubble Breaker type game, I broke my task into several smaller tasks, and I hit a wall.

I created a 2D Array Grid which will, whenever the program starts, be randomized with different coloured Bubbles. Each Line and Each Column is numbered, Lines range in Numbers, Columns range in Letters.

My goal is to have the user input choosing a String (Note I can only use String, as I'm programming in a pre-designed console), for example B10, B9 or 10B.

I'm able to check if the characters are numbers or letters via

```
command.charAt(i) >= '0' && command.charAt(i) <= '9' // i is a counter in a for
```

The above allows me to find if it's a digit or a number, the problem is that to select the Exact grid position, I need to, and can't:

- Separate the String into Integrers AND character
- Join the two Integrers
  (note they can be B9, B10 or 10B)

[This is an example of the duality B10 and 10B](http://tinypic.com/r/2h4ayd0/5)

Comment: Yes, it's java, I forgot to add the tag before, but I did it now, thank you :)

Comment: Is `"10B"` the same as `"B10"`?

Comment: So you just want to separate B and 10?

Comment: Scriptwise that's one of the problems, while for the user it's the same (Line 10, Row 2) (Row 2, Line 10), for the program it isn't.


Yes, Separating the B without separating the 1 and the 0 (therefore 10) is one of the problems. It would be easy, but I don't know in which position/lenght they will have (B10 = 10B / B9 = 9B)

Comment: Have you consideres using Regular Expressions to make the parsing of the string easier?

Comment: The only input the console takes is Console.NextLine(int) and it comes out as a string, so I can't use those expressions, Ideally that's what I would've done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need two lines:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
String letter = str.replaceAll("\\d", "");
```

The order of letters and digits in the string is irrelevant - this will work either way.

#### Edited to cater for requirements as per comments below

To process a series of letter-digit pairs in larger string, parsing the letter to an `int x` (where A=1, B=2, etc) and assigning the digit(s) to `int y`, you can split the string up on whitespace and use code similar to above:

```
for (String pair : command.toUpperCase().split("\\s+")) {
    int x = pair.replaceAll("\\d", "").charAt(0) - '@';
    int y = Integer.parseInt(pair.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
}
```

Using `split()` means not having to sully yourself with the tedium  of using a loop variable.

The reason for subtracting `'@'` is that is the character one before `'A'`, so subtracting that will convert `A` to `1`, `B` to `2`, etc.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String command = "A5 B10 11C 20D";
for (String pair : command.split("\\s+")) {
    int x = pair.replaceAll("\\d", "").charAt(0) - '@';
    int y = Integer.parseInt(pair.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
    System.out.format("X = %d, Y = %d\n", x, y);
}
```

Output:

```
X = 1, Y = 5
X = 2, Y = 10
X = 3, Y = 11
X = 4, Y = 20
```

Comment: @peeskillet thanks for noticing :) "Less code is good" is my motto (as long as it's readable). It's amazing how a little regex kung fu can drastically reduce the amount of code you need.

Comment: @peeskillet thx! that was fast. do you need any votes (gave you top answer a boost already)? it is xmas after all

Comment: This is a great awnser to the question, but I have to stick with peeskillet's method, The next piece of code I have is exactly to convert characters into integrer values which depend on other factors (The user can select grid size and position, which influentiates the coordinates given), So the other method allows me to just include that missing link in the alerady existing code. It's a great awnser and I really appreciate it though :)

Comment: Do you mean it has to work at index `i` of `command` within the loop?

Comment: Yes, because of the following code. The single letter (char) is converted to an X integrer coordinate while the other integrer is also converted to an Y integrer coordinate. This method wouldn't allow me to do it with the current code, or at least, I am not  experienced enough to make it happen

Comment: So you've got a String like `A5 10B C1` and you want to get `x=1,y=5` and `x=2,y=10` and `x=3,y=1`?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply, but Christmas didn't exactly allowed me to focus on programming. Anyway, Yes, it appears to be something that I should definently consider although I have to add something to convert lowercase to Uppercase. I'm trying this : `if (tempx >= 33){ x= tempx - 33;}` where `tempx` is the `x` on your original code. Is it a reasonable assumption? (A or a must come back as 0)

Comment: In your examples, `"A"` seems to be `1`, not `0`. Which is it?

Comment: I have fixed the lowercase/uppercase issue - see edit to answer where I added `toUpperCase()`. If A corresponded to 0 (instead of 1), subtract `'A'` instead of `'@'`.

Comment: You stole My check Mark! :P (guess that adds to your hat total)

Comment: @peeskillet actually already had the pirate hat :) I'm wearing it!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, just use an if loop. (If the first char is a digit, parse all but the last as an integer, otherwise parse all starting from the second as an integer.) (use String.substring(start, end) to separate it if that's all you want to know)
Also, you can use  `Character.isDigit()`  instead of

```
command.charAt(i) >= '0' && command.charAt(i) <= '9'
```

(just for code legibility)

Comment: That's true, but then I wouldn't be able to separate the character while keeping the numbers together to create an integrer

Answer (score 0):

- Loop through the String
- Check if character is a letter
- Save that letter to a variable (`char letter`)
- Replace the original String such that the letter is replace with nothing (`String numString`)
- Now you have them separated: `letter` and `numString`
- This will work with `B10` or `10B`. And set that has only one letter and the rest numbers

See code

```
String code = "10B";

char letter;

for (char c : code.toCharArray()){
    if (Character.isLetter(c)){      // if the character is a letter, save if the "letter"
        letter = c;
        break;
    }
}

String numString = code.replace(letter, "");  // replace the original string, letter for ""
// Parse if you need to 
int num = Integer.parseInt(numString);

// You have the letter by itself, and the number by itself    
System.out.println("Letter: " + letter + ", Number: " + num);
```

**Edit:** Try the code below. I had a couple errors in one above

```
    String code = "10B";

    char letter = ' ';    // <-- initialize

    for (char c : code.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {      // if the character is a letter, save if the "letter"
            letter = c;
            break;
        }
    }

    String numString = code.replace(String.valueOf(letter), "");  <-- String valueOf
    int num = Integer.parseInt(numString);
    System.out.println("Letter: " + letter + ", Number: " + num);
```

Result : `Letter: B, Number: 10`

Comment: I got an error testing that code:

´The method (char,char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char,String)'  I tried fixing it and I simply can't find any error(that I can fix) with it

Comment: You mean .reaplace()?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes at String numString = code.replace(letter, "");

Comment: Exactly, this solved it =) I tried to initialize it aswell, but what really cracked it was that .valueOf(letter) . Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it =) Now I can apply it on the grid, once again, thank you

Comment: Can you give me one more push please? I divided that code into two, one that gets me the number and another that gets me the letter. On both codes I treat the information to get a coordinate on the grid. My problem is, I get a runtime error when I run it, because the String is null in the beggining, I tried giving it a value but it had no effect, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at projecto.MotorDeJogo.getcv(BubblesBreaker.java:201) `  which is : `String numString = test.replaceAll(String.valueOf(letter), "");` The same happens with getch().

Comment: Actually, I am dumb and already solved it by `try` and `catch`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringSpliter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    String str = "T23his i43s a Stin4g Whi12ch C1on3431tains Ch 5ara32cter2343s and Alphabets";

    char[] mychars = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < mychars.length; i++) {

        if (mychars[i] >= 33 && !(mychars[i] <= '9' && mychars[i] >= '0')) {
            chars.add(mychars[i]);
        } else if (mychars[i] >= '0' && mychars[i] <= '9') {

            ints.add((Integer.parseInt(""+mychars[i])));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.size() + ints.size(); i++) {
        if (i < chars.size()) {
            System.out.println(chars.get(i));
        } else {
            System.out.println(ints.get(i - chars.size()));
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Try the above code